# VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue.js project in **Typescript**, I started

> npm run serve

I kept getting

```
>98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                          2:36:43 PM

 error  

Template execution failed: ReferenceError: VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH is not defined

  ReferenceError: VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH is not defined
  
  - index.html:4 eval
    [.]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html:4:11
  
  - index.html:13 module.exports
    [.]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html:13:3
  
  - index.js:284 
    [trace]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:284:18
  
  - runMicrotasks
  
  - task_queues.js:95 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5
  

No type errors found
Version: typescript 4.1.6
Time: 3996ms
```

[image]

## .env

line 5: I have this

```
VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH=./
```

Does Vue.js compiler look for that flag in another file that I should add ? Am I effected by some kind of cache issue ?

Comment: try to remove dot. instead of "VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH=./" use "VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH=/"

Comment: @AleksandarĐokić, the value of the variable doesnt matter. I assume it doesnt read the env file. code8888 try to export the variable once in your shell to see if it works. If it does work, you know the .env file is not read.

Comment: how do you access the variable?